# Firebase Dynamic Link Click Count

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

We are planning to integrated firebase dynamic link to track content sharing and referrals in our app.
Firebase provides analytics data for how many times a user clicked on a url as mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/analytics).
Since we are going to generate these links programmatically for referrals, is there any way to do a more granular tracking ? 
Like if I want to see how many times *all* the links generated were clicked.
Or something like how many times a link with a particular parameter was clicked.
I tried looking through firebase docs but I don't think these usecases are covered there.
And if thats correct, what is a better way to track this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to collect the analytics data for programmatically created dynamic links, you'll have to use [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/analytics#rest_api). Though, I also think that you can use BigQuery but I haven't tried this before. Collecting the data via Firebase Console is not yet available.